azure function core tools error on Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875
I'm getting
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5907 Commit hash: N/A +807e89766a92b14fd07b9f0bc2bea1d8777ab209 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875
The system cannot find the file specified.
Press any key to continue....
nothing changed on my system but it started to throw this error and I don't know how to fix it or where to start
I updated VS and restarted everything

Please provide your function code.

Usually this error occurs when the Core Library is updated.  The error is due to the version of the Core Tool library in the csproj file doesn't match the version installed on the machine.  I usually in VS go to solution explorer and delete the library (Core Tools) in the References.  Then add the reference to the project.  When the reference is added the correct version of the library will be added to the csproj file.


As @jdweng mentioned in the comments, delete the  %LocalAppData%\AzureFunctionsTools  folder, it deletes the cache of function core tools.
Open the Visual Studio and run the project, it regenerates the Azure Functions Tools folder automatically.


The issue could also be due to missing certificate as mentioned in SO by in @Mahesh Dharward.
Try adding the certificate in the Visual Studio and rebuilding the function project.
Refer the blog to generate the certificate Azure Functions host is expecting to find.
Debug the function using the command func host start --verbose and check if there is any issue with the function code:

